# What does Permission denied mean when I attempt to download Ubuntu as a Windows Vista program?

Tags: permissions, downloads, windows-vista

I am using a Dell Inspiron B130 with intel Pentium M and 32 bit Windows Vista.  Is my equipment or system too old?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu do you want to install and what is the spec of your PC?

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are trying to do, download Ubuntu or install it using wubi.exe?

Answer (score 4):

With Vista Microsoft introduced the User Account Control system (UAC) and it's likely that you do not have Admin rights to download programs (.exe files).

You can turn UAC off by following the steps on this [Microsoft Guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-vista/Turn-User-Account-Control-on-or-off)

Comment: Forgot about that in Vista.

Comment: I would prefer the latest version but will settle for what will work for me.  My Local disk has 31.6GB free of 74.4GB.  The processor is Intel(R) Pentium(R) 1.70GHZ; RAM 2.00GB; Type 32-bit.

Comment: PS For at least one of about 6 attempts to download I was signed in as Administrator.

Comment: PPS  Based on some pages I printed during the process, I was Installing using Wubi.

Comment: Turn off UAC and you will be able to install via WUBI.